# Fastest way to encode cyrillic letters for url

Tags: javascript, string, url, hex, cyrillic

If you copy the link below into the browser

```
http://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/Беларусь
```

it will show the Wiki article. 
But once you want to copy that link (or any other link that contains cyrillic symbols) from the browser url into the notepad, you'll get something like this:

```
http://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C
```

You can click on any link in the wikipedia that contains cyrillic letters in the text and try to copy it into the Notepad.

So, my question is:

What's the most correct or fastest way to convert any text that contains cyrillic word `Беларусь` into `%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C` or any other text into such type of code so it is a valid part of the URL?
Is there a special javascript function for that purpose?

I've checked, it is actually : cyrillic capital letter Б = (hex) D0 91 for UTF-8. That's why it is %D0%91 and so on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The function you're searching for is `encodeURIComponent`.

```
encodeURIComponent("Беларусь");
// returns "%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C"
```

Its counterpart is `decodeURIComponent` which reverses this process.

```
decodeURIComponent("%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C");
// returns "Беларусь"
```

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised this works for me submitting a webdav post request body. Using `escape` hadn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

I guess `encodeURI(string)` should be what you are looking for. Just check out already existing answers to the same question e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)!