# passing non-English character parameters in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect, url-encoding

I have a problem passing my parameters in springMVC.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String homePost(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        StringBuilder redirect = new StringBuilder();
        String para = request.getParameter("keyword");

        redirect.append("redirect:/search?" + "cat=0&job="+ para);
        logger.info("Page called: SEARCH; Called parameter: KEYWORD: " + redirect.toString());

        return redirect.toString();
}
```

In my console, I can see:

> Page called: SEARCH; Called parameter: KEYWORD:
>   redirect:/search?cat=0&job=lol лол lol

But my URL is

> http://localhost:8088/search?cat=0&job=lol%20%20%20%20%20lol

I set my all encoding in "UTF-8" and I am trying to search from list using Cyrillic but it keeps converting Cyrillic letters into empty spaces. I can search using Latin letters. If I write in the URL manually using Cyrillic letters, I can also search. 
In the console, it also shows

> bind => [%lol     lol%]

Thank you.

P.S Even if I did not use StringBuilder, I have the same problem. 
P.S.S My web.xml has

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272494/fastest-way-to-encode-cyrillic-letters-for-url

Comment: Are you using Tomcat? See "How do I change how GET parameters are interpreted?" in http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answers. I solved the problem and if anyone is interested.
@Alex 's link was so useful.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String homePost(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder redirect = new StringBuilder();
        String para = request.getParameter("keyword");

        redirect.append("redirect:/search/" + URLEncoder.encode(para, "UTF-8"));
        logger.info("Page called: SEARCH; Called parameter: KEYWORD: " + redirect.toString());

        return redirect.toString();
    }
```

And get method is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search/{keyword}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String job(Model model,@PathVariable String keyword) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String job = URLDecoder.decode(keyword);
        return null;
}
```