# Angular 4 with .Net Core 2 Cyrillic encoding is not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, character-encoding

I am unable to work with Cyrillic strings in my project. I am using .Net Core 2 with Angular 4.2.5 When I try to display a string in my templates like `{{ someCyrillicString  }}` it works but when I try to pass a Cyrillic string to a  function or when I try to `console.log("тест");` I get ������� I also created a .Net Core 2 project without Angular and there were no problems. I searched for a solution but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Read http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Check [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685859/javascript-processing-cyrillic-input). They already posted answer to a similar problem.

Comment: I tried that it didn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. The problem with the encoding only occurred in the files generated by Visual Studio so I just deleted and recreated them and the problem was gone.